# How can you let the name of a list depend on Userinput?

Tags: python, list, user-input

I have three lists in my code and I want that the names of the lists depend on the Userinput.

I have these 3 lists:

> a1 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
>
> a2 = ["q","w","e","r","t","y"]
>
> a3 = ["a","z","e","r","t","y"]

And there is a Userinput for example:

> bca

And then, I want that the names of the lists change: a1 -> b, a2 -> c, a3 -> a.

> a = ["a","z","e","r","t","y"]
>
> b = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
>
> c = ["q","w","e","r","t","y"]

Can anyone helps me?

Comment: lists don't have names. You have created three variables that happen to reference list objects, of course, there is nothing stopping you from referencing another object with those variables, or for multiple variables to reference a single list object. You probably just want to use a dictionary, there is no need for dynamic variables here.

Comment: You can use `global()["a"] = a3` to assign dynamic variable names.

Answer (score 1):

If you can consider to use a dictionary:

```
lists = [a1, a2, a3]

user_named_list = {}
for i, l in enumerate(lists):
  user_named_list[input(f"Enter a name for list {i}: ")] = l

print(user_named_list)
#=> {'q0': ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e1', 'f1'], 'q1': ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e2', 'f2'], 'q2': ['a3', 'b3', 'c3', 'd3', 'e3', 'f3']}
```